# Create space between two stacked svg images

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm adding two SVG images to an existing HTML page that includes existing CSS modules.

I can only add them using the
`{% includes ……..%}` statement if it’s in the folder structure below:
[image]

The SVG images will not add to the existing HTML using the `img`tags per the code below:

```
<img class="step-img" src="./_includes/svg/icon-comm-of-prac-discu.svg" alt="" />
```

In addition, I'm positioning them using an existing CSS module named "project-position-2" that has this code:

```
 .project-position-2 {
  text-align: center;
  }
```

Here is the HTML code to add both svg images and a live screenshot of what they look like:

```
<div class="project-position-2">
<img class="step-img" src="./_includes/svg/icon-comm-of-prac-discu.svg" alt="" />
{% include svg/icon-comm-of-prac-discu.svg %}
<div class="project-position-2">
{% include svg/join-comm-of-prac.svg %}`
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have tried adding padding and margins to the existing CSS, within the HTML and to the SVG image attributes and none of them are taking effect in putting space between the top and bottom of the SVG's.

Comment: You could just add a couple <br /> tags to provide the separation.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I thought of that, however, it seemed unelegant.  I didn't see that type of coding in other existing pages.  However it worked nicely.

Comment: `.step-img { margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px; }`

Comment: Hi Michael, I've seen that code in the existing pages.  I'll edit it tomorrow and circle back with the results tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. In `HTML` you can add couple of new lines by < br> tag.
2. In `CSS` it can be done by selecting your class and applying
   **`padding`**(if the div only contains the image)
   eg code:-
   `.project-position-2 { padding-top : 5%; padding-bottom : 5%; }`

   Or

   you can apply **`margin`** too
   eg code:-
   `.project-position-2 { margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom : 15px; }`

Comment: Hello Uttam, thanks for the specific code.  I'll try both your and Michael's ideas and circle back with results tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @Michael Rovinsky The update is that if I use the '{% include ......%} to add the svg image, nothing I've found (including using a flex container) "talks" to the images to add spacing between them (L, R, T or B).  If use the 'img' tag to add them to the HTML code, then all of the CSS changes/attributes work.  what is the difference between using the '{% include ......%} to add the svg image vs. using the 'img' tag to add them to the HTML code?  It's still a vector graphic in either format.  Is it due to the 'img' class?

Comment: hey! was my answer helpful to you? @codechick

Comment: The update is that if I use the '{% include ......%} to add the svg image, nothing I've found (including using a flex container) "talks" to the images to add spacing between them (L, R, T or B). If use the 'img' tag to add them to the HTML code, then all of the CSS changes/attributes work. what is the difference between using the '{% include ......%} to add the svg image vs. using the 'img' tag to add them to the HTML code? It's still a vector graphic in either format. Is it due to the 'img' class? @Uttam